# Getting to a single section in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Is it possible to display only a single section of reporu in JasperReports? I would like on one of the pages show only a section .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it depends on which sections you are going for (perhaps indicated by a certain parameter for part of the data from the database). You can use the Group feature.

This is a good example of breaking a report into sections:

http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/samples/DataSourceReport.html ([see more examples](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/samples.html))

You may display a section by querying the database with the specific entries you want by having your jrxml file expect a parameter in the query (The above example doesn't show it, but you can specify in your query to find entries with "Dallas").